# libcurl C++: long delay in detecting the change of a HTTPS response code

Tags: c++, curl, web-scraping, https, libcurl

**Problem:**

Using `libcurl`, the program below listens for a change in a web page's `HTTPS status code` when it changes from `503` to `200`. Recently however, **and without making any changes to the code**, there has been a substantial delay (around 18 seconds) between the sending of the final request (just when the page is being updated), and a response notifying that `200` is detected. So the page is updated with code `200` long before the program actually detects this and prints an output.

It's almost as if the program "hangs" at the page's update time and it cannot send or receive any requests, but only when the status code is being changed.

Notes:

- **Spikes in web traffic are not causing this delay.** This is a well-known site that can handle high traffic
- The owner of this site has said that **no other users are experiencing these delays**, and from their back-end confirmed that my IP address has recieved the data in a timely manner
- The sending program has a typical latency of around 3 milliseconds from the server hosting the webpage
- Using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS with `libcurl` installed using `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`

**Details:**

This issue began to appear around **mid-July 2021**. Up until this point, the program used to listen for around 10 seconds on the run-up to a predetermined time of 18.45. At 18.45, the page would update its status code to `200` and the program would usually grab this new data in around 100 milliseconds.

As seen further below, this program uses a `WHILE` loop to send a request that returns the response code. On the run-up to page update, `503` is returned each time as expected, and when `200` is detected, a `break` is used to exit the `WHILE` loop and print the output.

To diagnose this, `libcurl` has been uninstalled and reinstalled, and separate servers with different `IP addresses` have been used (just incase the initial `IP address` was blocked from making requests for whatever reason.) The issue still persists.

**Current program:**

```
#include "omp.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <future>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

#include <curl/curl.h>

// Function for writing callback
size_t write_callback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata) {

        std::vector<char> *response = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<char> *>(userdata);
        response->insert(response->end(), ptr, ptr+nmemb);
        return nmemb;
}

// Handle requests to URL
long request(CURL *curl, const std::string &url) {

        std::vector<char> response;
        long response_code;

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "");

        auto res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &response_code);

        if (response_code == 200) {
            std::cout << "200 FOUND" << std::endl;

            // print out payload
            // print out timestamp using <chrono>
        }

        return response_code;
}

int main() {

        curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
        CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();

        while (true) {
            long response_code = request(curl, "https://somewebsite.xyz");
            if (response_code == 200) {
                break; // Page updated
            }
        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        curl_global_cleanup();
        return 0;
}
```

**Summary questions:**

**Q1.** Are there any mistake in the above code which would be causing this behaviour?

**Q2.** Have there been any updates to `libcurl` over the last few months that may have affected my program? As previously stated, the program worked perfectly up until **mid-July 2021**, and the code has not been changed whatsoever.

**Q3.** Could I have changed some sort of setting that would prevent the server from replying to my request quickly? Each request while the webpage's code is `503` is returned very quickly, but as soon as the page is updated to `200` the request takes a long time.

Comment: **there has been a substantial delay (around 18 seconds) between the sending of the final request** How do you know this? Your program does not perform any measurements and does not even log any status except 200. I would start with `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1L); curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1L);` to make sure in **a typical latency of around 3 milliseconds from the server hosting the webpage**.

Comment: I should have included this but wanted to keep the code cleaner for viewers. I print an `EPOCH` timestamp every time a request is completed and I print the `response code` that is returned. At approximately 1 second before the scheduled page update, the time taken for a response containing the new response code `200` is approximately 18 seconds.

Comment: @p.luck Have you used a packet sniffer to verify that the underlying network traffic is actually being delayed 18 seconds?  It could just be a problem in your app that is delaying sending the request, and the response is actually being sent back immediately at the expected time.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for your reply and apologies for the slow response. I can only run this exact test once per week. I have created a new reformatted question with additional information in the form of a `Wireshark` output, and an output shown from debugging print statements. I'm still unable to fully ascertain where the bottleneck is coming from. If you had a spare moment or are interested in following, the new question can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69455532/libcurl-c-long-delay-in-response-from-server