# libcurl C++: long delay in response from server

Tags: c++, curl, networking, https, libcurl

I have a `libcurl` program running on `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS` that downloads a webpage's data when it detects that the webpage's `HTTPS status code` changes from `503` to `200`. When the code changes, it means the site owners have uploaded new info to the page.

I used to be able to detect the change from `503` to `200` in around 150-200 milliseconds consistently for months.

Since around mid-July 2021 however (and without changing the `libcurl` program's code whatsoever), when the site changes from `503` to `200` I do not get a response for anywhere **between 7 to 18 seconds to tell me the code has changed.**

**Note:** I have spoken to other users who have confirmed that they are still recieving the updated data in sub 200 milliseconds, as well as the site owners who described everything as working as normally.

**Current output/ attempts to solve:**

1. Uninstalled and reinstalled `libcurl` with `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`
2. I decided to use `Wireshark`, [the output of which can be seen here [use code 173967 if required/ happy to do so]](https://www.filepastebin.com/8edeb31c-f8fb-47d7-8ecf-d91722d5cd7c). The scheduled change of the `status code` is usually at/after `1633012200`. The `libcurl` sending IP is seen as `192.168.0.29` and the destination is `13.224.247.34`, but I cannot ascertain if the information is indeed being delivered on time and my application is causing the bottleneck, or if there is a genuine network issue.
3. Employed debugging print statements. One statement prints `"sent"` when the response code request is sent, and the other prints `"received"` with the returned response code and an `EPOCH timestamp`.
   On the countdown to the website's scheduled change from `503` to `200`, in the terminal I see the expected output of `sent -> received -> EPOCH timestamp`. When the website's scheduled change from `503` to `200` occurs, all I see in the terminal is `sent`, followed by a 7 to 18 second delay before an output of `received 200 -> timestamp`.
4. Tested the same code with the same URL on three separate servers with different `IP addresses` but with the same OS, which all produced the same delayed result although some slightly less slow than others.

An example of `print statement` output:

```
/*
listening...

sent
response
503
1632925797111

sent
response
503
1632925797227

sent
response
503
1632925797336

sent
    <---- Program hangs here for approx. 7-18 seconds before printing 200 and timestamp*/
```

**Current code:**

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <future>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

#include <curl/curl.h>

// Function for writing callback
size_t write_callback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata) {

        std::vector<char> *response = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<char> *>(userdata);
        response->insert(response->end(), ptr, ptr+nmemb);
        return nmemb;
}

// Handle requests to URL
long request(CURL *curl, const std::string &url) {

        std::vector<char> response;
        long response_code;

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "");

        auto res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &response_code);


        if (response_code == 200) {
            // do something
        }
        return response_code;
}

int main() {

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();

    std::string value1;
    std::cout << std::endl << "Press 1 to start listening..." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> value1;

    if (value1 == "1") {

        std::cout << std::endl << "listening..." << std::endl;

        while (true) {
            std::cout << "sent" << std::endl;
            long response_code = request(curl, "https://someurl.xyz");
            std::cout << "response" << std::endl;
            if (response_code == 200) {

                std::int64_t epoch_2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
                std::cout << "code 200 detected at : " << epoch_2 << std::endl;
                break; // Page updated
            }
            else {
                std::cout << response_code << std::endl;
                            std::int64_t epoch_3 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
                            std::cout << epoch_3 << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_global_cleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

**Summary question:**

**Q1.** Given that other users are not experiencing this and I have ran this same test on different servers with different IP addresses, does anyone know what could be causing the delay of my program detecting the status code change? As previously stated, this program worked as expected with little to no delay before July 2021.

This issue has been ongoing for over three months. If anyone has any ideas, or could possibly point me in a direction to diagnose this, I would be highly appreciative.

Comment: Are there any proxies involved? You could try adding some random data to the URL: `https://someurl.xyz?foo=1323453545` (and make it a different number ever time). That may trick the proxies to not send you a cached page.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks for the reply. The exact format of the URL is: `https://www.site.xyz/folder/file.txt` ... so could I add some random data as is in `https://www.site.xyz/folder/file.txt?foo=1234`? What would the benefit of not being sent a cached page be?

Comment: Yes, that looks like it could work. A caching proxy may decide to not go out to fetch pages for all requests. Instead it stores pages for some time and just sends the stored pages to save bandwidth - which means that you wont see updates on that page, even if it has been updated. By adding random data to the request it's sometimes possible to bypass that behavior. It doesn't really have to be random. You could just have a counter that you increase for every request you send.

Comment: I'll give this a go during the test tomorrow and will report back, thanks for the suggestion. Do you know why there could ever be a reason that the code used to work, and then one day require this potential solution?

Comment: Great! Hope it is that simple. Reason: It could be that someone turned on caching on the corporate proxy.

Comment: Okay thanks for the info, I appreciate it. I'm also going to run the same script on Windows just to see if that makes any difference, as well as switching on `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` to see if I can get any more details. I've seen some others with a similar problem speaking about DNS resolution issues. I did have a kernel update last week that affected my PCs DNS, but this particular libcurl issue has existed for months. Do you think it could maybe have some relation to DNS issues?

Comment: Oh... yeah, there's a lot of nasty stuff out of the application's control that could change the behavior. If the site has changed its IP number but had a really long time to live in the DNS record, it could make your packets go to the wrong IP number for example. That would probably not show up like this, but it would also cause confusion. Bad routing tables could also mess it up. I've had bad routing where my packets suddenly took a turn over the atlantic and back. Nothing I could do but to mention it to my ISP :-)

Comment: Routing packets across the Atlantic sounds like a stressful scenario to not be in control of. It's been tough trying to diagnose this, but I'll have a go with your suggestion plus a few other tests I'm going to carry out tomorrow and will report back. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Yes - it totally messed up my gaming :-) You're welcome! You could also try to find out where it takes time by running a traceroute program for some time. PingPlotter is popular but commercial (but the 14 first days are free I just read - I have no affiliation with them).

Comment: Great, I'll take a look at PingPlotter. Could I perhaps use the `traceroute` command in the terminal also, and run this at the same time I execute my `libcurl` program?

Comment: Sure, you could run `traceroute` instead. PingPlotter does a very similar thing. You don't have to run your `libcurl` program at the same time but it shouldn't hurt too much if you do (unless your LAN or WLAN is really close to reaching its bandwidth limit).

Comment: Okay sure, I’ll probably use PingPlotter instead of trace route. Thanks!